# print() method of a socket output stream doesn't work

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

I'm trying to write a code for a simple chat app with java sockets. This is the code of the server

```
public class MyServerSocket implements Runnable {

    List<Connexion> connexions = new ArrayList<>();
    final int PORT=7878;

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println ("I'm waiting for clients to connect");
            Socket socket = null;
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("A client is connected, IP : " + socket.getInetAddress());
                Connexion connexion = new Connexion(socket);
                connexions.add(connexion);
                Thread process_connexion = new Thread(connexion);
                process_connexion.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // serverSocket.close();
    }

    public void broadcast(String message) {
        this.connexions.forEach(connexion -> {
            if (connexion != null) {
                connexion.sendMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }

    class Connexion implements Runnable{

        private Socket socket = null;
        private String nickName;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public Connexion (Socket s) {
            this.socket = s;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream IS = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(IS);
                in = new BufferedReader(ISR);
                OutputStream OS = socket.getOutputStream();
                out = new PrintWriter(OS, true);



                // here is the problem
                // when i replace println with print method
                // the code won't work any more
                out.println("Hi Client");
                out.println("Enter your name : ");





                String requete = in.readLine();
                this.nickName = requete;
                out.println("You are connected, you can type what you want!");
                while ((requete = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    broadcast(this.nickName + " : " + requete);
                    System.out.println(requete);
                }
                out.println("Connection lost!");
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        public void sendMessage(String message) {
            out.println(message);
        }

    }

}
```

The code is working, but when i replace the mentioned println method (above in the code), or any println method related to output stream of socket, to print problems occur.

When i use println, the output of the server looks like
[output of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53auB.png)
and client output  looks like
[client output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWrCd.png)
But when i use print instead,  the output of the server looks like
[output of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOsS9.png)
and client output looks like
[client output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWcrV.png)
I use the same code of client in the two exemples.
My question is why the print method doesn't work like println does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

Since you're not calling `println` anymore, there will be no automatic flushing. Call `flush()` manually to send the data.

Comment: You're welcome.